# Generalization of elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

The [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) (ESPs) are defined as -

\begin{align*}
E_{1}^{1} 
&= X_1,
\\
E_{1}^{2} 
&= X_1 + X_2,
\\
E_{2}^{2}
&= X_1 X_2,
\\
E_{2}^{3}
&= X_1 X_2 + X_1 X_3 + X_2 X_3,
\\
E_{k}^{n} 
&= \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < \dotsb < j_k \leq n} X_{j_1} \dotsm X_{j_k}. 
\end{align*}

Notice that in the above examples, all the coefficients are 1.

Now we can generalize $E_{k}^{n}$ by the following function

$$ G_{k}^{n} = \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < \dotsb < j_k \leq n} S_{j_1 \cdots j_k} \: X_{j_1} \dotsm X_{j_k}, $$

where $S_{j_1 \cdots j_k}$ is symmetric. If $S_{j_1 \cdots j_k} = 1$, the above equation reduces to the ESP.

Edit: although $S_{j_1 \cdots j_k}$ is symmetric, $G_{k}^{n}$ is not (in the previous versions I incorrectly wrote $G_{k}^{n}$ is a symmetric polynomial).

My questions are -

1. Does the polynomial $G_{k}^{n}$ have a name?
2. Do decompositions of $G_{k}^{n}$ exist, like the ESP (by [Lee - Power sum decompositions of elementary symmetric polynomials, 2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2015.11.018))?

I apologize if my notations are not standard. I have edited some of them to look familiar.

Comment: I don't see how $G_N^M$  are symmetric, unless I misunderstood the hypotheses. Minor point: you seem to be using very non-standard notation for what is a very standard object in symmetric functions theory.

Comment: Edited. Thanks!

Comment: The polynomial is still not symmetric, unless all the $S $es are equal.

Comment: As @darijgrinberg [implies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366878/generalization-of-elementary-symmetric-polynomials#comment926848_366878), I  think you may be running into the confusion about "how symmetric".  A symmetric polynomial is symmetric in *all* its variables, whereas a symmetric tensor is symmetric only in the indices that are passed to it.  (I'm also not sure what you gain by thinking of tensors here.)  For example, any degree-1 tensor, say $S_i = i$ in the index notation, is symmetric; but $G^2_1 = X_1 + 2X_2$ is not a symmetric polynomial.